# Handle Content-Encoding gzip in Annotated Service

Tags: armeria

I have an annotated service. Some clients POST requests with the content in plaintext. Other clients POST requests gzipped and include the header `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

The gzipped requests are failing to be decoded as proto values, because they are not unzipped first.

How do I decorate my action so that it selectively gunzips the body based upon the header value?

```kotlin
  @Post("/foo/bar)
  @Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
  @Produces("application/x-protobuf")
  fun setFooBar(
    request: SetFooBarRequest,
    headers: RequestHeaders,
  ): SetFooBarResponse { ... }
```

fails with `Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.` (ie this blob is not a proto value), but only for requests where `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DecodingService](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.linecorp.armeria/armeria-javadoc/latest/com/linecorp/armeria/server/encoding/DecodingService.html) automatically decodes `gzip`, `deflate` and `brotli` by default. You can apply `DecodingService` using `ServerBuilder.decorate()`.
For example:

```java
Server.builder()
      .annotatedService(new MyProtobufService())
      .decorate(DecodingService.newDecorator()) // 
      .build();
```